# What is the meaning of "I don't fault people people their suspicions" from the last line of the paragraph given down below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Or worse, I sound like I am trying to hide from myself. **I don't fault people their suspicions.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly means that he doesn't find fault with people because of their suspicions. I have never seen that exact structure:
"I don't fault people their suspicions." before.
I'd call it a solecism.